# Drag and Drop..upload file into Feeditem content..Please help

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, jquery

HI i am trying to use drag and drop for uploading file into content.
Below code works for attachment

**`sfdcurl = '/services/data/v27.0/sobjects/Attachment/';`**

When i tried to change it Feeditem object it doesn't work.Please tell me if the url is wrong or anything else i am doing wrong.

**`sfdcurl = '/services/data/v27.0/sobjects/Feeditem/';`**

```
 <script>

              var curPopupWindow = [];

            var headersData = {}; 
            headersData["Authorization"] = "Bearer {!$Api.Session_ID}";
            sfdcurl = '/services/data/v27.0/sobjects/Feeditem/';
            Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
            var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#dropzone-email-dropable", {
                        maxFiles: 25,
                        url: sfdcurl,
                        addRemoveLinks:true,
                        dictCancelUpload:"Cancel Upload",
                        dictCancelUploadConfirmation:"Are You Sure?",
                        dictRemoveFile:"Remove",
                        parallelUploads:2,
                        filesizeBase:1024,
                        maxFilesize:10,
                        //autoProcessQueue:false,
                        //params: {"ParentId" : "{!contentFolderId}","Description" : "{!sessionId}"},
                        params: {"ParentId" : "{!contentFolderId}"},
                        headers: headersData,
                        init: function () {
                            this.on("maxfilesexceeded", function (data) {
                                var res = eval('(' + data.xhr.responseText + ')');

                            });
                            this.on("removedfile", function (file) {
                                console.log(file.uploadId);
                                this.deleteFile(file,this.options.url);
                                //refreshAttachments();
                            });
                            this.on("success", function (file,resp) {
                                file.uploadId = resp.id;
                                //refreshAttachments();

                            });

                        }
                    });
               console.log({!success});            
            </script>
```

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to your question?

More importantly, I'm curious if the multi-file upload is working for you, and are the files attached directly as attachments through the API or did you have to write a controller or go through a proxy to make it work?